# How to learn the active uipickerview when clicking toolbar's done button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview, toolbar

I have two `UITextFields`, two `UIPickerViews` and one `UITabBar`, which has 'done'/'cancel' buttons. They have these settings:

```
textField1.inputView = pickerView1
textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
textField1.inputView = pickerView2
textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

I need to update related textField's title when clicking on the 'done' button.

```
func donePicker() {
    // Update textField1
    if (xxx) {
        println("PickerView1 is showing up")
        textField1.text = textArray1[pickerView1.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    }

    // Update textField2
    if (xxx) {
        println("PickerView2 is showing up")
        textField2.text = textArray2[pickerView2.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    }

    // Dismiss keyboard
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

As each textField has its own placeholder value, we should not change the other textField's placeholder value when updating one's title.

I don't know how to write the if condition 'xxx' part. How can I get the active uipickerview when clicking the done button? Are there any APIs/properties, such as pickerView1.isActive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I get it via the text field being edited.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if (textField == textField1) {
        pickerType = "pickerView1"
    }
    if (textField == textField1) {
        pickerType = "pickerView1"
    }
}
```

Thanks all for your review, and thanks @matt for the comments.